# Concatenate files through -cat from a Python script

Tags: python, bash

I have a folder full of files whose names look like this:

```
"Code1_B1_1.1.fq.gz"
"Code1_B1_2.2.fq.gz"
"Code1_B2_1.1.fq.gz"
"Code1_B2_2.2.fq.gz"
...
"Code5_B1_1.1.fq.gz"
"Code5_B1_2.2.fq.gz"
"Code5_B2_1.1.fq.gz"
...
...
```

etc.

These are DNA sequences. I want to concatenate these files according to the Code number AND the extension. Thus, for example, my files "Code1_B1_1.1.fq.gz" and "Code1_B2_1.1.fq.gz" will be merged in a single "Code1_both_1.1.fq.gz".

Using bash (as a novice), I found out how to list the files I need to concatenate, for example :

`ls | grep -E "Code1.*.1.1.fq.gz"`

but how can I concatenate them afterwards ? I wanted to simply use the command -cat and save the output into a new file, but how do I retrieve the files I was able to list with -ls ?

... also, ultimately, I would like to perform the whole thing from a Python script that would automatically merge all my files according my two criteria (Code and extension) :)

Thank you in advance for your help!

Chrys

Comment: (There was a "Hello everyone" at the very beginning of my message but it won't appear here!! Sorry about this!

Comment: Because this is gziped files, you cannot just use cat. But, you can use zcat.

Comment: Are the quotes really part of the names? So, for instance, does `ls "Code1_B1_1.1.fq.gz"` show the file (in which case the quotes are syntactic, an instruction for the shell, **not** part of the filename), or does it need to be `ls '"Code1_B1_1.1.fq.gz"'` (in which case the outer quotes are syntactic and the inner quotes are literal)?

Comment: Thank you so much guys! Charles, the quotes are not part of the filenames, I was just hoping it would be more clear like this :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`ls` output is for human use, not programmatic consumption; see [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Instead, use a [glob expression](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs) to form a list of filenames:

```
zcat Code1*1.1.fq.gz >outfile
```

...or...

```
gunzip -c Code1*1.1.fq.gz >outfile
```

If you need to quote parts of this name for some reason, you can do that so long as you *don't* quote the `*` (or any other glob-expression metacharacter):

```
gunzip -c "Code1"*"1.1.fq.gz"
```

Note that glob expressions are a bit different from regular expressions: In regex, `.` is a special character -- so `grep -E "Code1.*.1.1.fq.gz"` would also match `Code1AB1C1DfqEgz` as a valid name, since each and every `.` in the expression is treated that way. In globs, `.` is not special, and `*` means zero-or-more-of-anything (as opposed to zero-or-more-of-the-last-thing)

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try this! Have a very nice evening!

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you Charles! Sorry to disturb again, but now I would like to know how to use this command with a relative or absolute path? Indeed, the command will be launched by my Python script that works on another folder (the working directory won't be the same as my list of sequence files). Thank you again!

Comment: I found a solution, but unfortunately, something weird happens. I wrote this: zcat ../../Folder/Code1*1.1.fq.gz > essai.fq.gz

I am absolutely sure the relative path is good. Still, it returns me that there is no such file or directory and therefore creates an empty "essai" file. Would you have any idea what the problem could be ?

My command works perfectly well with two little .txt files I created to make diverse tests, but when I go back to my sequences, nothing :( !

Comment: Does `printf '%q\n' ../../Folder/Code1*1.1.fq.gz` really print filenames? This looks like the path just isn't valid relative to your current location. BTW, if you want your output to be another `.gz` file you don't need to use `zcat` at all -- you can concatenate a bunch of gzip files together to make another gzip file and it'll just work, so regular `cat` is fine.

Comment: This command does not give me the list of files, however `ls ../../Folder | grep "Code1.*.1.1.fq.gz"` does, is there any difference in the way relative path works with ls and cat? I am sure I am missing something obvious but right now this seems really odd! 

Thank you so much again for helping me :)

Comment: @Chrys, in regex syntax (as used by `grep`), `.*` means the same thing as `*` in glob and `.` means the same thing as `?`, and matches aren't anchored on either end, so the most literal equivalent would be `printf '%q\n' ../../Folder/*Code1*1?1?fq?gz*`. Of course, I'm assuming you *really do* want to look for `fq.gz` and not to allow any other characters there, and that there aren't really prefixes or suffixes on the filenames, but we can tighten up the glob expression to be less permissive after we've found one that works.

Comment: This seems very encouraging, I could not try to run this within my complete pipeline yet but it works after a smaller test! Thank you so much Charles for your help! Have a very very nice day!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to list all files and then grep for the files you want and store it in a file.

ls -ltra | egrep -e 'Code1_B1_1.1.fq.gz|Code1_B1_2.2.fq.gz|Code1_B2_1.1.fq.gz|Code1_B2_2.2.fq.gz' > filename

OR

ls | zip -@m filename.zip

Comment: Please see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs. If you want to list names for programmatic use, it's safer to use `printf '%s\n' *` than `ls`, as the manner in which `ls` escapes nonprintable characters is undefined by its specification. Even `printf '%s\n'` can be badly confused by names with literal newlines; NUL-delimited streams (`printf '%s\0' *`) are the only truly safe way to list completely arbitrary filenames.